# How to give extra options to featureGroup in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am new to leaflet js. I am trying to add some extra options to my featureGroup layer but it is not working.

```
var marker = L.marker(point, { icon: iconMarker, data: random, class: 'hugo', id: random });
var circle = L.circle(point, {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        radius: 20
    });


var PoleLayer = L.featureGroup([marker, circle], {
        options: {
            attribution: "Pole Group",
            extra:"extra value",
            id:"some id"
        }
    });
```

For Marker i am able to access options but in the case of PoleLayer i am not able to set any extra options or access those options can any one help me out here.

How should i assign extra options to featureGroup in leaflet js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since leaflet 1.7 you can set custom options when creating a feature group:

> L.featureGroup(<Layer[]> layers?,  options?)

Reference:
https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#featuregroup

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup

The `featureGroup` method doesn't take an options argument.

```
L.featureGroup( <ILayer[]> layers? )
```

I think you are doing it right, you set the options on individual markers and pass it to `L.featureGroup`.

Instead extend `PoleLayer` like this:

```
PoleLayer.options = {
  attribution: "Pole Group",
  extra:"extra value",
  id:"some id"
};

console.log(PoleLayer.options);
```